# C# Selenium Webdriver Count Xpath Elements / null check

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, webdriver

How would you convert the count of xpath to int?

```
int example = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//td[contains(@sorttable_customkey, '" + Account + "')])/preceding::a[1]")).Count;
```

I picked this up from question: [Does anyone know why GetXpathCount() doesn't work in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970977/does-anyone-know-why-getxpathcount-doesnt-work-in-c/14998668#14998668)

I can't seem to get it to work, I tried dumping the above to a list and counting the list but this also wouldn't work.

Also sort of off topic but is there a way to check if driver.FindElement(By.XPath("exp")) == null? because if it dose = null it will throw a null reference error.

Comment: "_I can't seem to get it to work_" is a pretty poor problem description.  If you want help, you have to describe the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `.FindElements`.

After all, look at the method name of what you are using: **FindElement**. (no plural)

Therefore, the count will always be 1 ;)

Check out `.FindElements`, this will have a `.Count` property (because it's essentially a `List` that is returned).

As for the null checking, that is down to you but it is unneeded. The source code of Selenium shows it will never be null returned from there. It's either going to be the element you asked for, or an exception is thrown if it has trouble getting it.

So a `null` check would be defensive, but wasteful. Even more so since that `.FindElements` will just return *an empty collection* if it has trouble getting the element you are asking for (i.e compared to throwing an exception).

Therefore realistically speaking, you'd only get a `NullReferenceException` if `driver` was null (which would mean your entire test fails).

```
int numberOfElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("(//td[contains(@sorttable_customkey, '" + Account + "')])/preceding::a[1]")).Count;
```

Comment: I thought I tried this last night and it was throwing an error, although I was coding for 12 hours straight so I could of done somthing else wrong. Anyway thanks and thank you as well Santoshsarma both are correct.

Comment: "_Therefore, the count will always be 1_" Even worse, there is no `FindElement().Count` property, because what `FindElement()` returns is not a collection :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FindElements](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_ISearchContext_FindElements.htm) if you have a same locator for more than one element.

It will return ReadOnlyCollection, using that you can get `count` of elements:

```
int example = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("(//td[contains(@sorttable_customkey, '" + Account + "')])/preceding::a[1]")).Count();
```